# CXF RequestContextFilter

Tags: cxf

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/30-migration-guide.html

> CXF RequestHandler and ResponseHandler filters have been removed,
>   please use JAX-RS 2.0 ContainerRequestFilter and
>   ContainerResponseFilter and also WriterInterceptor and
>   ReaderInterceptor when needed.

**How to rewrite it? I cant find any examples taking org.apache.cxf.message.Message as a parameter and returning Response.**

Also I should use the ContainerResponseFilter

```
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext, ContainerResponseContext containerResponseContext) throws IOException {
```

instead of RequestHandler

```
Response handleRequest(Message m, ClassResourceInfo resourceClass)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `RequestHandler`

```
public class CustomRequestHandler implements RequestHandler {
    public Response handleRequest(Message m, ClassResourceInfo resourceClass) {
```

with `ContainerRequestFilter`

```
public class CustomRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {
        Message m = JAXRSUtils.getCurrentMessage(); 
        OperationResourceInfo m = message.getExchange().get(OperationResourceInfo.class);
        ClassResourceInfo resourceClass = operation.getClassResourceInfo();
        // finally use context.abortWith(Response) if you need to block the request
```

Replace `ResponseHandler`

```
public class CustomResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler {
    public Response handleResponse(Message m, OperationResourceInfo operation, Response response) {
```

with `ContainerResponseFilter`

```
public class CustomResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter  {
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext inContext, ContainerResponseContext outContext) throws IOException{
        Message m = JAXRSUtils.getCurrentMessage();
        OperationResourceInfo operation = m.getExchange().get(OperationResourceInfo.class);
        //outContext has the capabilites of javax.ws.rs.Response. For example outContext.setStatus(201);
```

Spring

```
<bean id="customRequestFilter" class="com.CustomRequestFilter" />
<bean id="customResponseFilter" class="com.CustomResponseFilter" /> 

<!-- Add filters to provider zone in JAX-RS server-->
<bean id="myRestServer" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSServerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false" init-method="create">
    ...
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="customRequestFilter" />
            <ref bean="customResponseFilter" /> 
        </list>
    </property>
```

Comment: Use `context.abortWith(Response)` in `ContainerRequestFilter` to set the custom response

Comment: `ContextRequestFilter` is executed before processing, therefore you haven't any response yet. If you want to modify specific `Response` properties after processing, you need to work with `ContainerResponseContext` in `ContainerResponseFilter`. For example `outContext.getEntity()`. `Response` object is not directly available