# How to reject non-https request with Apache cxf / jaxrs

Tags: tomcat, https, jax-rs, cxf, servlet-filters

**What I need to do:**
I need to figure out how to reject any incoming http requests that are NOT over TLS (i.e. https). Ideally I would be able to return an http status of 404 (not found) if the request is NOT over https.

**What my implementation looks like:**
I am implementing a REST service using Apache cxf / jaxrs.
I am using Spring's IoC to create the service.

The service definition in the Spring application context file looks like this:

```
<jaxrs:server id="testSvc" address="/">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="svcBean"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>    
</jaxrs:server>
```

The service is running inside of Tomcat.

I am thinking of using a simple servlet filter or a jax-rs filter (e.g. something that extends javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter).

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish tomcat only on SSL/TLS, but I guest you can not do this, so you can detect if you are in a SSL session. To access the SSL session ID from the request, use:

```
//Tomcat 6
String sslID = (String)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.ssl_session"); 

//Tomcat 7
String sslID = (String)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id");
```

See [tomcat SSL documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

Finally set a `ContainerRequestFilter` in CXF to access request parameters and abort response if needed

```
public class SSLFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

   public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {

       //get current httpservletRequest from CXFMessage
       Message message = JAXRSUtils.getCurrentMessage();
       HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);

       //Get SSL session ID
       String sslID = (String)request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.ssl_session"); 

      // finally use context.abortWith(Response) if you need to block the request 
       if (sslId == null){
           Response response =   Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
           context.abortWith(response);
       }
  }
```

Add the `provider` to you server

```
<bean id="sslFilter" class="SSLFilter">
<jaxrs:server id="testSvc" address="/">
   <jaxrs:providers>
      <ref bean="sslFilter" />
   </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Comment: good response, but in my question I identify ContainerRequestFilter as a *possible* solution, but ask the question: "Is there a better way to do this?"

I am looking for a solution other than a servlet filter or a ContainerRquestFilter.

Comment: The simplest solution is to disable the http protocol on tomcat or on your SSL proxy. But I assumed that you would need for other services.
Accepting http / https the appropriate solution is a filter. A J2EE standard filter will not allow customization per server. You could also consider using a CXF interceptor, but it is not so simple abort the request. Since CXF3.0  `ContextRequestFilter` are available for this type of actions (preprocess the Message before service method called)

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I am stuck on CXF 2.2.12. The ContextRequestFilter does not exist in that version. So, I ended up using a CXF interceptor. It seems to be working fine.

Comment: If you do not like interceptors, for CXF 2. 2 you could use RequestHandler instead of ContextRequestFilter. they are similar, check differences here http://stackoverflow.com/a/37730218/6371459